# Need to modify my regex to catch different representation of essentialy the same sentence

Tags: python, regex, pdf, text

Okay, so I am working on parsing PDF files to only get "SECTION 2".
I will show you some examples from the PDF files I am working on.
[image: Start]

[image: End]

I need to catch everything in SECTION 2 (between the two pitcures)
Here's my regex (work in progress)

```
re.findall('hazards*\sidentification(.*?)information\son\st*h*e*\s*ingredients', text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

note: sometimes it's information on "the" ingredients.

I've tried different approaches like using "SECTION 2" and "SECTION 3" but in some files, it's just "2" and "3" so I reached this.

So far my regex worked correctly on 95% of the files because of files with different sentences like this:

[image: Notice how section 3 is written]

And this:
[image: Same issue]

And other various issues like this. I tried making my regex capture with only the word "Hazard" and the word "Composition", but they appear in some files before section 2 and thus it catches the wrong part.

I can ofc write multiple regex to catch all combinations, but what if my script sees a brand new file? I don't think this is efficient at all.

Any ideas how I'd go around this?

I can provide more info about the project if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a single regex for all documents ever... I wouldn't even try. I would just handle the "SECTION 2"/"SECTION 3" case until the regex doesn't work. From the documents where regex1 doesn't work, group them into buckets that follow a pattern and write a new regex for that bucket. Repeat until you've classified the documents into a few buckets and have a regex for each.